# Issue while using .AAR file in the project

Tags: android, kotlin, aar

I have created my custom android library and now wants to use this library in another project. Here is what I did so far:

1. Created a library project in Android Studio. Build that project, so .aar file was generated like: ..\MyApplication\mylibrary\build\outputs\aar\mylibrary-release.aar
2. Created a new Android project in Android Studio. Then, I followed this:

app<<Created a library project in Android Studio. Build that project, so .aar file was generated like: ..\MyApplication\mylibrary\build\outputs\aar\mylibrary-debug.aar

Created a new Android project in Android Studio. Then, I followed this:

1. Created a libs directory under the app and paste the .aar file. This is the structure in my project:
   [image]
2. Navigate to File > Project Structure > Dependencies.then click + and select Jar Dependency in the dropdown.
3. In the Add Jar/Aar Dependency dialog, added the path of the .aar file and select the "implementation" configuration.
4. added implementation files('my_path/my_lib.aar') in build.config file
   [image]

Now, if I try to use class name of my Library project. There is one class MPPush.java in my library project.  I am not able to see MyClass. It shows No suggestions instead.

[image]

[image]

I am using Android studio Arctic Fox. Am I missing some configuration?

Comment: right click on your .aar file, there will be option "Add as library", click on it so it will be added in your build.gradle and then sync.

Comment: Did you sync your project with gradle?

Comment: @Bennik2000 yes i did.

Comment: @pratikvekariya there is no option "Add as library" when i right click on .aar file.

Comment: then file > Projecct Structure > select "Dependencies" from left side > now select "your app" > after selecting app in middle you can see all dependencies in your app , above that there will be "+" and "-" sign > click on "+"  > you can see options > select "Add jar/aar dependencies" > you can see your aar file

Comment: check this https://i.stack.imgur.com/85tZv.png